# parquet column pruning in spark

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I know parquet supports read user selected columns only. But when I use

```
dataframe.read.parquet().select(col*)
```

to read the data, it looks like still read the whole file. Is there any way in spark to read the selected column chunks only?

Comment: "it looks like still read the whole file"  - how did you determine that? Also please include structure of the data and Spark version.

Comment: in the spark web UI, the input size/read IO is the total number of the file size.

Comment: spark version is 2.1.0.cloudera1, table is the lineitem in TPC-H